# Tooltip doesn't show some characters when hovering over a link to a question

Tags: bug, tooltips

That's what I see:

[image]

But the [real](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449778/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-instead-of-backticks-in-shell-scripts) content is:

> What is the benefit of using $() instead of backticks in shell scripts?

The `$()` didn't show up.

Comment: Looks like it's reconstructed from the URL, it's all lowercase and the question mark is missing too.